# MongoDB to Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, mongodb-query

i have a problem while importing the MONGODB to NEO4J.  The error is showing like this "Failed to invoke procedure 'apoc.mongodb.first' : Caused by : java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create MongoDBClientWrapper instance"